# How to print duplicate records if greater than 2?

Tags: awk

How to print duplicate records which is repeated more than 2 time using awk.

Input:

```
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
8|O315L4UB1BGTW03QRQW8L6J3936
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
```

Expected output:

```
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
```

I tried below command, but i am not getting exact output.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$2]++; next} cnt[$2]>2' input > output
```

Comment: `cnt[$2]>2` only prints if the record is repeated *more* that 2 times but your statement says *maximum* 2 times. Which is it? You might try `cnt[$2]>=2`...

Comment: More than only, but when i execute above query it returns 0

Comment: after changing cnt[$2]>=2 output returns zero

Comment: Given the construction of the awk, you need to feed the file twice.

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
cat file
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
8|O315L4UB1BGTW03QRQW8L6J3936
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
```

You can produce your output like so:

```
awk -F $'|' 'FNR==NR{data[$2]=data[$2] ? data[$2] ORS $0 : $0; cnt[$2]++; next} 
             {if (cnt[$2]>=2) {print data[$2]; delete cnt[$2]}}' file file
```

Prints:

```
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
```

---

Commented (explained) version:

```
awk -F $'|' 'FNR==NR {  # FIRST PASS
                        data[$2]=data[$2] ? data[$2] ORS $0 : $0 # line ORS line for each match
                        cnt[$2]++                                # count matches
                        next                                     # next line
                     } 
                     # SECOND PASS
                     {if (cnt[$2]>=2) { # two or more?
                           print data[$2] # print matching lines
                           delete cnt[$2] # only print once
                           }
                     }' file file >output
```

Comment: Output returns zero

Comment: awk -F $'|' 'FNR==NR{data[$2]=data[$2] ? data[$2] ORS $0 : $0; cnt[$2]++; next} 
             {if (cnt[$2]>=2) {print data[$2]; delete cnt[$2]}}' input > output like this only i execute

Comment: `input > output` won't work. That is only reading `input` once.

Comment: You need two passes over the file. The `FNR==NR` part is only executed for the FIRST pass and the rest of the awk is only executed on the second pass.

Comment: but the record size is 10Million. how it will run in screen itself. its better to write in another file

Comment: awk -F $'|' 'FNR==NR{data[$2]=data[$2] ? data[$2] ORS $0 : $0; cnt[$2]++; next} {if (cnt[$2]>=2) {print data[$2]; delete cnt[$2]}}' input input > output like this did we need to give

Comment: Thank you so much.Command worked. Could you please give me the explanation for that. I am not understanding.

Comment: Explanation added

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single-pass simply by saving the first record of each `$2` seen and then on the second occurrence -- output the saved record and set a print flag indicated this `$2` has now been seen twice, e.g.

```bash
awk -F"|" '
  {
    seen=($2 in r)      # have we seen record before?
    if (!seen)          # if not
      r[$2]=$0          # save first record
    a[$2]++             # increment counter for record
  }
  
  a[$2] == 2 {          # if 2nd time we have seen record?
    print r[$2]         # print saved record
    p[$2] = 1           # set print flag for record
  }
  
  p[$2]==1              # print all remaining occurrences of record
' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file` you would get:

```
awk -F"|" '
>   {
>     seen=($2 in r)      # have we seen record before?
>     if (!seen)          # if not
>       r[$2]=$0          # save first record
>     a[$2]++             # increment counter for record
>   }
>
>   a[$2] == 2 {          # if 2nd time we have seen record?
>     print r[$2]         # print saved record
>     p[$2] = 1           # set print flag for record
>   }
>
>   p[$2]==1              # print all remaining occurrences of record
> ' file
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
```

Comment: yours doesn't guarantee the input sorting order. I ran shuffle on the input rows, and got ::: 5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA ( \n )
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA ( \n )
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ ( \n )
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ ( \n )
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW ( \n )
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW ( \n )
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H ( \n )
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H ( \n )
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW :::::::::::: the final line has been disjointed with its siblings

Comment: That's a fair point, that wasn't a goal here. Given the input/output, piping to `sort` will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

A one-and-half-pass `awk`-based solution that works across `gawk`, `mawk`, and `nawk` ::

- the approach here is that since the tail end of them are identical, no point to save N number of copies of it when the hash key is already the tail itself

  - so it only saves `$1` along the way, then using `gsub()` to batch place them back in the end
- downside being : it needs **2 arrays** in order to ensure original input order of `$2` while being cross-`awk` compatible, without using another sorting utility

```
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
     
    {m,n,g}awk'
    BEGIN {_+=_=__^=___=+(FS="|")
    }  {
    10      if (! ($_ in ____)) { # 5
     5          _____[++___] = $_
            }
    10      sub("$", ($__)"\1", ____[$_])
    } END {
     1                      RS = ++___
     5      for (__^=!_; __<RS;__++) {
     5          ORS = ____[_=_____[__]]
     5          if(_^!__ < gsub("\1","|"(_)"\n", ORS)) { # 4
     4              print ""
            }
        }
    }
```

—————————————

UPDATE 1 :: just realized I could make it quite a bit more succinct :

```
BEGIN { _+=_=__^=___=+(FS="|") 
} {
    if (!($_ in ____)) {
        _____[++___] = $_
    }
    sub("$",($__)"\1",____[$_]) 
}
END {       __=_= ORS = ""
                  FS  = "^$"
    while(++__<___) {
         $!+__=____[_ = _____[__]]
         print $( NF *= NF<gsub("\1", "|"(_)"\n") ) 
    } 
}
```